# How to customize the wufoo form by include own css file

Tags: html, css, forms

I have created wufoo form, this is the link for display popup form,

```
<a href="https://dev88.wufoo.com/forms/w1l9ro500payryl/" onclick="window.open(this.href,  null, 'height=777, width=680, toolbar=0, location=0, status=1, scrollbars=1, resizable=1'); return false">Please fill out my form.</a>
```

Now when view the form look like this,

[image]

Now i want know, how to include own css file to customize the form, can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

first you need to connect your stylesheet like so `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mysite.css">` and this file already spend styling

```
H1 {
 color: navy;
 font-size: 200%;
 font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
}

P {
 padding-left: 20px;
}
```

approximately so))

and it is better to show your code or codepen http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I am asking related in wufoo form.